# MYSQL Double Joining Tables and Inaccurate Counts/Sums

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I'm trying to generate a report that shows the top referrers and how much revenue the people they have referred have generated.

Here is an abbreviated version of my tables:

```
Users Table
------------------
id
referral_user_id (references another record in the users table)
username
firstname
lastname

Transactions Table
-------------------
id
user_id
amount
```

I have tried using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    users.id, 
    users.firstname, 
    users.lastname, 
    users.username, 
    COUNT(referrals.id) referrals, 
    SUM(transactions.amount) income
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `referrals` ON `users`.`id` = `referrals`.`referral_user_id`
LEFT JOIN `transactions` ON `referrals`.`id` = `transactions`.`user_id` 
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
ORDER BY `income` desc
```

And I get the following results:

```
ID  |   username    |   Name    |   Referrals   |   Revenue From Referrals
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       jj              Jason       136             6536.30
2       jim             Jim         206             2957.75
3       tim             Tim         67              2712.10
```

The only problem is the numbers don't add up. When I do the query `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE referral_user_id = 1`, I get a count of 77, and when I do `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE referral_user_id = 2`, I get a count of 161.

When I remove the transaction/income part of the query and just do this:

```
SELECT 
    users.id, 
    users.firstname, 
    users.lastname, 
    users.username, 
    COUNT(referrals.id) referrals
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `referrals` ON `users`.`id` = `referrals`.`referral_user_id`
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
ORDER BY `referrals` desc
```

I get the correct referral counts. Can anyone explain to me what I'm missing please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you are making a wrong assumption on how aggregate works in SQL.

Suppose you are joining like in your initial query without GROUP BY and aggregates, it could give for example the following data:

User 1 is linked with [2,3], has amounts [100,200] leading us to 4 records when joining

```
ID  |   username    |   Name    |   referral_user_id    |   Amount
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       jj              Jason       2                       100
1       jj              Jason       3                       200
1       jj              Jason       3                       100
1       jj              Jason       2                       200
```

Using your query will group on the results above:

- leading to count 4 instead of 2
- leading to sum 600 instead of 300

Note it isn't helping puting COUNT(referrals.id), COUNT(1) will give the same result for instance.

For the referals you could use COUNT(DISTINCT referrals.id), IF AND ONLY IF you are not counting a relationship between a and b multiple times.

Else and for sure for the amounts you should solve it with a subquery.

Comment: Thank you Sam Segers! That was it... I changed "COUNT(referrals.id) referrals" to "COUNT(DISTINCT referrals.id) referrals" and that made everything add up. Thank you!